# Get table name with apps script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have two tables, namely Table A and Table B. Each table I want to identify the name of the table in column C matches the table names that have been defined in column A.

The script I've made is like this:

```
tableName () function {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  let cColumn1 = ss.getRange ('C3: C7');
  let cColumn2 = ss.getRange ('C11: C15');
  
  let tableName1 = ss.getRange ('C2'). getValue ();
  let tableName2 = ss.getRange ('C9'). getValue ();
  
  cColumn1.setValues   (tableName1);
  cColumn2.setValues   (tableName2);
}
```

But my script is still manual, we have to specify the start line and end line of the table.

To identify the name of the table I've ever made with a formula, so with this formula, we don't need to specify the position the name of the reference table.

```
= ARRAYFORMULA (IF ((B: B = "") + (B: B = "Name") ,, VLOOKUP (ROW (A: A), IF (LEN (REGEXEXTRACT (A: A, "T\D+") ), {ROW (A: A), REGEXEXTRACT (A: A, "T\D+")}, 0), 2)))
```

This formula is very heavy if the amount of data is large.

[My Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eQuOz6GOL88PjwMql4CC7QctsiEqXsQIa4T429vzG8A/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Table A and Table B; they are stacked, one above the other in columns A, B and C and there is no other data in Columns A, B or C. Each table may be any number of rows long and there is a single blank row between each table. The name of Table A is in cell A1; the name of Table B is in Column A in the row following the blank row after Table A.

You want to populate cells in Column C with the respective table names. You have a formula (Cell E1) but this formula takes too long if there is a lot of data. So you want a script to populate cells in Column C and the script must dynamically calculate the ranges that apply to each Table.

Though the script in your question is manually updated, it fails because `setValues()` expects a two dimensional array (the values must match the dimensions of the range) but your input value is the value of a single cell.

**Points to note:**

- The key column is Column A. `getLast Row()` is not used because it will return the last row for the entire sheet and this does not necessarily represent the data in Column A.
- the Javascript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is used ("ALast") to determine the last row for only Column A.

  - Since there is a blank row in Column A (which is ignored by the `filter` method), a value of 1 (one) must be added to "ALast" to determine the actual last row of content.
- the content of Column A is analysed through a loop;

  - a table counter is used to distinguish between table 1 and table 2.
- the output is added to temporary arrays and the ranges are updated with the `setValues()` method.

  - the Javascript [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method is used to build the temporary arrays since the content for each array is multiple instances of the same value.

---

```
function wa14315803wa() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "wa_143158"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // calculate the number of rows in Column A
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row in column A = "+(+Alast+1))

  // range variables
  var outputCol=3;
  var table1StartRow=3;

  // Table counter
  var table = 0;  

  // there are no blank rows except for between table A and Table B
  // so it is safe to start at row 0
  for (i=0;i<Alast+2;i++){

    // test for empty row and table counter = 0 (Table 1)
    if (Avals[i][0] == "" && table==0){
      // this is table A (the first table)
      // row is empty
      // table A ending range = i (since rows start at 0)

      // get the Table name from cell A1
      var tableName1 = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Name of Table 1 = "+tableName1);

      var table1EndRow = i;
      var table1NumRows = table1EndRow-table1StartRow+1

      // define the output range for the first table
      var cColumn1 = sheet.getRange(table1StartRow,outputCol,table1NumRows);
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: cColumn1 range = "+cColumn1.getA1Notation());

      // update the output for Table1
      var table1array=[];
      table1array.length = table1NumRows; // set array size
      table1array.fill([tableName1]); // fill array with any value    
      cColumn1.setValues(table1array);

      // increment table counter
      var table = 1; 

      // define the start row for Table 2
      var table2StartRow = i+4;
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: table2StartRow = "+table2StartRow);

    }

    // test for empty row and table counter = 1 (Table 2)
    if (Avals[i][0] == "" && table==1){
      // this is table B (the second table)
      // row is empty

       // get the Table name
      var tableName2 = Avals[(+i+1)][0];
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Name of Table 2 = "+tableName2);

      var table2EndRow=Alast+1;
      var table2NumRows = table2EndRow-table2StartRow+1
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: table2EndRow="+table2EndRow+",table2StartRow = "+table2StartRow+", table2NumRows = "+table2NumRows);

      // define the output range for the second table
      var cColumn2 = sheet.getRange(table2StartRow,outputCol, table2NumRows);
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: cColumn2 range = "+cColumn2.getA1Notation());

      // update the output for Table2
      var table2array=[];
      table2array.length = table2NumRows; // set array size
      table2array.fill([tableName2]); // fill array with any value   
      cColumn2.setValues(table2array);

    break;
    }

  }

}
```